# How do I display different name and different landing page to each grid item?

Tags: mobile, dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am trying to build a grid item view and each item should have a different text and different landing page. For example, Android development grid item, when clicked should go to Android Dev. page and Web dev grid item, when pressed should navigate to web dev page.

This is my current display and I want every grid item to have a different name.
[image]

```
var gridView = new GridView.builder(
        itemCount: 2,
        gridDelegate:
            new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new GestureDetector(
            child: new Card(
              elevation: 5.0,
              child: new Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: new Text('Android Development')),
            ),
            onTap: () => _navigateToQuizPage(context),
          );
        });

    return new DefaultTabController(
      length: 1,
      child: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Flutter TabBar"),
          bottom: tabBarItem,
        ),
        body: new TabBarView(
          controller: tabController,
          children: [gridView],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _navigateToQuizPage(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => new AndroidQuiz()));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would suggest using the default [GridView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html) constructor instead of `GridView.builder`. You can simply add the cards with the adjusted titles and routes to it. In this example I use different routes for the different final views.

Another solution would be to pass a parameter to a route, and change the view based on the parameter. If this would be the appropiate solution for your problem, please leave a comment and I'll edit this answer to provide an example.

Standalone example (without the next views):

[image: GridView Demo]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyGrid(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(crossAxisCount: 2, children: <Widget>[
      MyCard(title: 'Web Development', route: '/web'),
      MyCard(title: 'Android Development', route: '/android'),
    ]);
  }
}

class MyCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String route;
  final String title;

  MyCard({this.route, this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, this.route),
      child: Card(
        child: Center(child: Text(this.title)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```